# How to create query with format date DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: database, postgresql

I have query database like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE start_date = '01-10-2016' //DD-MM-YYYY
```

But above code error and actually in database date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.
So how to create query with format date `DD-MM-YYYY`?

Comment: obviously, you need to disclose the data type of your `date` column.

Comment: i have edited with column name start_date

Comment: The column name is irrelevant. The data type of the column is essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper date column ([**data type `date`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) !) has no format. Then it's enough to get your data input for a date column right, use `to_date()` for non-standard input format [like @Shiva posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40415169/939860). Or better yet, always provide date literals in ISO 8601 format 'YYYY-MM-DD' to begin with, which works with *any* locale setting.

***If*** you are running a broken design with **dates stored as text**, then combine [`to_date()` and `to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) to transform any valid date format into any other text format:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE  start_date = to_char(to_date('01-10-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `to_date` function to convert the above format into the standard format.

For instance,

```
SELECT to_date('01-10-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
----------
2016-10-01
1 row
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/to_date.php

Comment: how to code above change if i have column 'start_date'

Comment: @ione swap out '01-10-2016' in the example above with 'start_date'.