# Determining first activity for the day per user

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table "UserData" with the following information in it:

```
User    Date    DateTime        Input
1   8/4/2019    8/4/2019 0:55   Request
1   8/4/2019    8/4/2019 0:56   Ticket
1   8/4/2019    8/4/2019 2:08   Submit
1   8/4/2019    8/4/2019 2:21   Submit
2   8/4/2019    8/4/2019 13:10  Submit
2   8/20/2019   8/20/2019 2:10  Ticket
2   8/20/2019   8/20/2019 2:12  Ticket
2   8/20/2019   8/20/2019 2:13  Request
3   8/20/2019   8/20/2019 2:15  Request
3   8/19/2019   8/19/2019 2:16  Ticket
3   6/12/2020   6/12/2020 2:22  Submit
3   6/12/2020   6/12/2020 2:26  Submit
3   6/12/2020   6/12/2020 3:26  Ticket
```

I'm looking to return the first input from each user (based on time) but only on the newest day. So my output would be something like this:

```
User    DateTime    Input
1   8/4/2019 0:55   Request
2   8/20/2019 2:10  Ticket
3   6/12/2020 2:22  Submit
```

I'm thinking that I need to assign a rank to each date but not really sure where to start on this one.

Comment: Your Postgres version and basic data distribution are essential to identify the best solution. How many rows total and how many distinct users, roughly? Also, is there a separate `users` table with one row per relevant user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `row_number()` window function:

```
select t."User", t."Date", t."DateTime", t."Input"
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by "User" order by "Date" desc, "DateTime") rn
  from UserData
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

For every user the row are sorted by `"Date"` *descending* to find the latest date and then by `"DateTime"` *ascending* to get the 1st input of that day.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bRmhpbhUvkxB5kyvEdywJ1/1).
Results:

```
| User | Date       | DateTime         | Input   |
| ---- | ---------- | ---------------- | ------- |
| 1    | 2019-08-04 | 2019-08-04 00:55 | Request |
| 2    | 2019-08-20 | 2019-08-20 02:10 | Ticket  |
| 3    | 2020-06-12 | 2020-06-12 02:22 | Submit  |
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want the earliest record per user and per day. In Postgres, you can simply use `distinct on` to solve this top-1-per-group problem:

```
select distinct on (u.user, u.date) u.*
from userData u
order by u.user, u.date, u.datetime
```

If you want the earliest record per user, regardless of the day, then just:

```
select distinct on (u.user) u.*
from userData u
order by u.user, u.datetime
```

---

Edit: if you want the earliest record on the latest day, then:

```
select distinct on (u.user) u.*
from userData u
order by u.user, u.date desc, u.datetime
```

Comment: "Only on the newest day" was what they asked. (Not my downvote)

Comment: This construct is awesome. I'd never come across it. However, the output he desired is "Oldest record on the newest day". So the sort would be `u.user, u.date DESC, u.datetime`

Comment: @ChrisHep: ah yes I think that you are right. That's just a slight change in the query, I edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM ( User,
       Date,
       Datetime, 
       Input,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY User 
           ORDER BY Datetime DESC) dataOrder
       FROM UserData) z
WHERE z.dataOrder = 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want:

***the row with the earliest time of the latest day for every user***

#### Table design

For starters: drop the `Date` column. Storing it redundantly adds more cost and complications than it's worth:

```
CREATE TABLE userdata (
  user_id  int
, datetime timestamp
, input    text
);
```

`input` should really be some cheap enumeration implementation (`enum`, FK, ...).
`timestamptz` might be the appropriate type for `datetime`. Depends. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

#### Index

Either way, to make your operation fast, this is the perfect index:

```
CREATE INDEX userdata_special_idx ON userdata
(user_id, (datetime::date) DESC NULLS LAST, datetime);
```

`datetime::date` is a *very* cheap cast, replacing your redundant date column. I still add the date to the [multicolumn expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html) for performance. (The *date* depends on the time zone when working with `timestamptz`. If you deal with multiple time zones you need to do more.)

Note the added `NULLS LAST`: since nothing in your question says that the the timestamp is `NOT NULL`, you need this in the query to prevent nonsense results - and the index must match for best results. See:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

### Query

For only ***few rows per user***, `DISTINCT ON` should be the best choice (like GMB already suggested) - simple and fast:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
       user_id, datetime, input 
FROM   userdata
ORDER  BY user_id, datetime::date DESC NULLS LAST, datetime;
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

For ***many rows per user***, this alternative query should be (substantially) faster:

```
SELECT u.user_id, d.*
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT d.datetime, d.input 
   FROM   userdata d
   WHERE  d.user_id = u.user_id         -- lateral reference
   ORDER  BY d.datetime::date DESC NULLS LAST, d.datetime
   LIMIT  1
   ) d ON true;
```

Typically, **this is the way to go** for your scenario.

Note the `LEFT JOIN`: it returns a row for every user, even with no entries in `userdata`. If that's not desirable, use `CROSS JOIN` instead. Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

This assumes the existence of a `users` table, which typically exists. If it doesn't, I suggest you add it (for multiple reasons). If that's not an option, there are still fast workarounds. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b30e8d08abf276931a669cbb567a55e2)*

Aside: I warmly recommend to *always* use ISO date format ([as does the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE)). Regional format depends on settings of the current session and may fail in ugly ways.

- [How to create query with format date DD-MM-YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415078/how-to-create-query-with-format-date-dd-mm-yyyy/40415311#40415311)